# How can i reach my content of href tag from c# to insert a link?

Tags: c#, .net, html

I'm trying to develop a RSS Management system and I want to put a link the href of `baslik1(title1)`. How can I do this?

HTML:

```
 <div class="sag-re-baslik" id= "baslik1" runat="server">
    <a href="#">A link that reader follows</a>
 </div>
```

C# (in there list array keeps all links of RSS feeds.)

```
 this.baslik1.InnerHtml = list[i].Title;
 this.icerik1.InnerHtml = list[i].Description;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the HTML you are trying to achieve? It's not completely clear from your question. Do you want  `<a href="#">list[i].Title (list[i]Description)</a>` or something different?

Answer (score 1):

If you could alter your html a bit we can easily do this

HTML

```
<asp:Panel ID="baslik1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    link.ID = "Feed" + i;
    link.NavigateUrl = "";
    link.Text = list[i].Title;;
    link.Tooltip = list[i].Description;
    baslik1.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

Comment: href is the navigateurl. insert the desired value there